# Automating parameter inputs from table in DB2 stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I am using the stored procedure shown here for deleting 12 huge tables by parameterizing the table name, commit count and where condition. I have inserted these 3 pieces of information into a table called `PURGE_DEL` which has 12 rows and I want some suggestions how I can automate deleting from 12 tables by reading from table one after another.

Something like

Table name : PURGE_DEL

```
CALL DELETE_DATA(PURGE_DEL.TABLE_NAME, PURGE_DEL.COMMIT_COUNT, PURGE_DEL.WHERE)
```

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_DATA
(IN V_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(24), 
IN V_COMMIT_COUNT INTEGER, 
IN V_WHERE_CONDITION VARCHAR(1024))

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 01
COMMIT ON RETURN NO
LANGUAGE    SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC

L3 : BEGIN

-- DECLARE STATEMENTS
DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER;
DECLARE V_DELETE_QUERY VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT STATEMENT;

SET V_DELETE_QUERY = 'DELETE FROM ' || V_TABLE_NAME || 
' WHERE COLUMN IN (SELECT COLUMN FROM  ' 
|| V_TABLE_NAME ||  'WHERE COLUMN_ID =' 
|| V_WHERE_CONDITION  || ' FETCH FIRST ' 
|| RTRIM(CHAR(V_COMMIT_COUNT)) || ' ROWS ONLY) ';

PREPARE V_DELETE_STATEMENT FROM V_DELETE_QUERY;
DEL_LOOP:
    LOOP
        EXECUTE V_DELETE_STATEMENT;
        IF SQLCODE = 100 THEN
            LEAVE DEL_LOOP; 
        END IF;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END L3
```

Please also suggest any changes for the stored procedure.

Comment: You have been already provided the solution in your previous post. Is this so hard to adapt that `FOR` loop to call your routine inside it?

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, you can avoid the costly self-join in your DELETE by using this style of DELETE

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE WHERE_CONDITION  
    FETCH FIRST 50000 ROWS ONLY
)
```

and, you could consider using MDC rollout deletion if you truly want efficient purging of rows

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0007338.html